# how can add keyboard shortcut ESC in vuejs or javascript?

Tags: vue.js

I want to add a keyboard in my vuejs app, when the user strikes the ESC key on the keyboard, then one of my buttons be selected, for instance, my first button which has shortKey:1 how can I do this?

here my HTML code:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" v-for="item in toolSet" 
     :key="item.shortKey">
     <i class="icon-cust" :class="item.icon"></i>
</button>
```

and here my vuejs code:

```
data() {
    return {
        toolSet: [{
                name: "hand-pointer",
                icon: "far fa-hand-pointer",
                shortKey: 1,
            },
            {
                name: "object-group",
                icon: "far fa-object-group",
                shortKey: 2,
            },
        ],
    };
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue, after a few hours which I faced it, here is the solution.

Note: just add the below codes on your project and don't do anything else(I mean is no need to use @keydown.esc and etc) :

```
mounted() {
        const items = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-dark");
        items[0].classList.add('btn- 
        first-styles')
        document.addEventListener("keydown", e => { 
             if (e.keyCode == 27) { items[0].classList.add("active_btn"); }
        }); 
        document.addEventListener('click', e => {
             items[0].classList.remove('active_btn') })
        }
```

if you receive an error like e variable doesn't use, this error because of eslint, and for rid of this error you have to disable eslint from package.json

Answer (score 1):

In a for loop the `key` prop is used to keep track of each node's identity for reactivity purposes, so it doesn't have to do with event handling.

What you are looking for is to use a `v-on` directive with a keyboard event like this

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" v-for="item in toolSet" v-on:keyup.esc="doSomething">
  <i class="icon-cust" :class="item.icon"></i>
</button>
```

You can also use the shortcut `@` like `@keyup.esc`.

Also starting in version 2.6.0 you can dynamically assign an event name to the `v-on` directive in the following way:

```html
<a v-on:[eventName]="doSomething"> ... </a>
```

If your version is > 2.6.0 you can do the following

```html
<button 
  type="button" 
  class="btn btn-dark" 
  v-for="item in toolSet" 
  @['keyup.' + item.shortKey]="doSomething"
>
  <i class="icon-cust" :class="item.icon"></i>
</button>
```

Here's some documentation references that you could find helpful: [`v-on` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html), [Key Modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers), [Dynamic Arguments](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Dynamic-Arguments).

Comment: thank you for your answer, still, I have one question that I can not find it on the internet or vuejs doc,  I want to add a keyboard  on the first button when the user strikes the ESC key on the keyboard, the first button  be selected, I don have much experience of vuejs and And I recently learned it, please help me, what condition I have added to `doSomthing` function that selected the first button
@sebasaenz

Comment: @Mohammad Please check the links I added to my answer.
`doSomething` is the function you want the keyboard event to trigger. You cannot "add a keyboard" to a button, but you can add event handlers for the events that you want: click, key events, etc. I hope you understand that I cannot give you a full explanation on Vue.js event handling here, but I would suggest that you check how does the `v-on` directive work. Hope it made everything a little bit more clear.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm solved this project one hour ago with Vanilla javascript.
and now wrote below of the project, anyway thanks for spending your time to answer me, best wishes. @sebasaenz